# Not able to access Id of button from embedded html

Tags: javascript, html, dom

This is app running in electron framework. The html is inserted as iFrame into main html.I have button with id. I want to enable and disable this button based onkeypressed event. I will paste the code what I tried.

File.js

```
function buttonEnable(){
  document.getElementById("Btn").disabled = false;//trying to enabl or disable 
  button with the help of Id 
}

function setData(){
  document.getElementById("proxyBtn").disabled = true;
  let FileData= "<form>";
  FileData+= '<td class="hostid-td-padding">';
  FileData+= "<input id=\"user\" type=\"text\" value=\""+user+"\" 
  onkeypress=\"buttonEnable()\"></input>";
  xmlFileData+= "</td>\n";   
  FileData+= '<td>';  
  FileData+= "<input id=\"Btn\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Save\" 
  onclick='update()'></input>\n";
  FileData+= "</td>";
  FileData+= "</tr>\n";
  FileData+= "</form>"; 
}
```

Comment: function buttonEnable() belongs to the iframe? dirty solution would be to inject your script inside fileData: `FileData+= "<script>function buttonEnable(){ document.getElementById("Btn").disabled = false;}</script>"`;

Comment: Thats working :), I want the button to be disabled in the beginning

Comment: Thats working now Grafi Thank you